# Ansible ec2.py runs standalone but fails in playbook

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, ansible

I've seen a few posts on this topic with odd hard to reproduce behaviours. Here's a new set of data points.

1. Currently the following works

`cd ./hosts
./ec2.py --profile=dev`

2. And this fails

`AWS_PROFILE=dev; ansible-playbook test.yml`

These were both working a couple days ago.  Something in my environment changed. Still investigating. Any guesses?

Error message:

`ERROR! The file ./hosts/ec2.py is marked as executable, but failed to execute correctly. If this is not supposed to be an executable script, correct this with`chmod -x ./hosts/ec2.py`.
ERROR! Inventory script (./hosts/ec2.py) had an execution error: ERROR: "Error connecting to AWS backend.
You are not authorized to perform this operation.", while: getting EC2 instances
ERROR! ./hosts/ec2.py:3: Error parsing host definition ''''': No closing quotation`

Note that the normal credentials error is:

`ERROR: "Error connecting to AWS backend.
You are not authorized to perform this operation.", while: getting EC2 instances`

...

Hmmm. Error message has shifted. 

`AWS_PROFILE=dev; ansible-playbook test.yml
ERROR! ERROR! ./hosts/tmp:2: Expected key=value host variable assignment, got: {`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was a temporary file in the hosts folder.  After removing it the problems went away.  It looks like std ansible behaviour: Pull in ALL files in the hosts folder.